# Do I have ability for remove child tag inside XML?

Tags: android

I'm trying read `Youtube captions(subtitles)` and every item has `<text>` tag.

*And let's take simple example from any video on Youtube :*

```
<text start="14.98" dur="3.64">
BUT YOU SHOULD THINK TWICE BEFORE YOU COME NEAR!
</text>
```

*But some videos has another tag inside `<text>` tag. For example :*

```
<text start="6.473" dur="2.168">
- <font color="#FFFFFF"><i>( playing ) </i> - <i>( fireworks popping )</i></font>
</text>
```

*In above we can find `<font>` and `<i>` tag inside `<text>` tag ,The main question do can I remove any tag inside `<text>` tag without select name because we can't guess know all tags in videos. , After remove any tag inside `<text>` I want read below only.*

```
( playing )( fireworks popping )
```

*Can someone leave simple code by java for explain how we can do it.*

I apprecaite your time , Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Html.fromHtml()` to parse the html string and get the `Spanned` which you can then convert (using `toString()`) to get your required string value.

So, for example,

```
String value = Html.fromHtml("<text start=\"6.473\" dur=\"2.168\">\n" +
        "- <font color=\"#FFFFFF\"><i>( playing ) </i> - <i>( fireworks popping )</i></font>\n" +
        "</text>").toString();
Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: "+ value);
//Would print "onCreate: - ( playing ) - ( fireworks popping )"
```

---

**Alternate solution** (Caution - Might not satisfy all edge cases) -

Removing the tags from the string using string parsing.you can try removing the tags using regex (for eg: `replaceAll("\\<[^>]*>","")`) or by using a library like [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org), but HTML escaping like that is difficult and some edge cases might get missed.

Comment: Not working with my code. But I got idea can I remove all tags from string ?

Comment: That's weird, I tested that code before posting. 

Comment: Yes, you can try removing the tags using regex (for eg: `replaceAll("\\<[^>]*>","")`) or by using a library like [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/), but HTML escaping like that is difficult and some edge cases might get missed.

Comment: Thank you so much.